# NT AUTHORITYShort Name?

Tags: security, winapi

I am trying to discover what the "short name" is in Widows 7/2008 for "NT AUTHORITY", I must pass that short name as a parameter to something that cannot take spaces in domain/computer names.

Thanks.

Comment: It might help if you tell us the name of the function...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a "short name" for `NT AUTHORITY`, AFAIK only accounts that are local to the machine can use it.

You did not specify which function you are trying to call but you can usually just use `"."`, `""` (empty string) or `NULL` for domain parameters when working with the local system.

Comment: The actual user is "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR".